# On Bra & ket notation

Tags: support, feature-request, mathjax

I was asking a QM question recently, and wanted to use the bra & ket notation; however, the MathJax does not support the necessary packages, as far as I can tell.

Is it possible to add the necessary requirement to the MathJax system so that we can use the bra & ket notation **easily** while asking question on Phys.SE ?

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6951/50583 See https://stackoverflow.com/q/21192606/3929857 for why one cannot simply add standard LaTeX packages to MathJax.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I didn't know that, thanks for the references.

Comment: Alternatively, use `|x\rangle` and `\langle x|` for $|x\rangle$ and $\langle x|$ respectively.

Comment: @Blue Well that is an option too, but it is still longer to write every single time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the mathjax does not support the necessary packages

This isn't true - MathJax has full support for the `\langle`, `|` and `\rangle` commands, as well as the combination `\left< \right>`, which are all you need to typeset bras and kets.

However, that said

> Is it possible to add the necessary requirement to the MathJax system so that we can use the bra & ket notation **easily**

yes, that's a nontrivial point. As mentioned in the comments, MathJax isn't LaTeX ─ it's a fully parallel system with completely different internals ─ and adding LaTeX packages isn't generally possible. As it happens, there *is* a specific extension that does this kind of thing, and whether to enable it or not is a narrower discussion [which it's better to have in a dedicated thread](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10989/why-dont-we-have-the-physics-mathjax-extension-enabled-should-we) (but the short answer is likely that the extension is too buggy to use at present, even if it were a good idea to enable it if it did work).

Outside of that, if what you want is ease of access, then the [MathJax Buttons](https://stackapps.com/questions/3373/mathjax-buttons) browser extension is an extremely convenient way to get seamless access to Dirac notation on the site's text editor.

Personally, I have modified the software end of my keyboard to have clean access to the unicode versions of the angled brackets (specifically, the `⟩` and `⟨` characters), and those compile just fine with the unicode support in MathJax, so that e.g. `$|x⟩⟨x|$` produces the output $|x⟩⟨x|$, with the benefit of single-keypress access as well as a vastly more readable source.

Comment: Regarding the edit (v2), that seems to contradict the accepted answer in the dedicated thread: Ben Crowell's arguments are largely against the physics extension in general (since it ruins comparability with other sites and makes brackets work differently and so on). His point 5 is the only one which talks about bugs, and it doesn't even speak about how disastrous the bugs are: it merely acknowledges the likelihood. The comments discuss the bugs, but... they're comments, and they're temporary.

Comment: I understand you've used the wording "even _if_ were a good...", which clearly doesn't imply that the bugs are the only problem, but I feel that it doesn't quite capture the strong community response in support of _not_ adding the extension for the diversity of reasons.

Comment: @Chair I'm a bit tired of this type of nitpicking. You're welcome to add your own answer if you disagree with this one.